# Bottom Sheet spacer takes up too much space on smaller screens

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have a SwiftUI bottom sheet view that **CAN** fit on the iPhoneSE, but it chooses to just have a huge spacer for no reason.

SwiftUI View

```
struct ExerciseSheet: View {
    @StateObject var exerciseShetViewModel: ExerciseSheetViewModel = ExerciseSheetViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        GlassCard(backgroundImageName: "exerciseBackground") {
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Group {
                    oneVerticalSpacer()
                    Text("Log Workout")
                        .Title2Bold()
                    
                    oneVerticalSpacer()
                }
                Group {
                    let exerciseTypebinding = Binding<ModelExerciseEventType?>(
                        get: { exerciseShetViewModel.state.activityType },
                        set: { exerciseShetViewModel.updateActivityType($0) }
                    )
                    CustomDropdown(
                        optionSelected: exerciseTypebinding,
                        title: "Activity Type",
                        options: ModelExerciseEventType.allCases
                    )
                    oneVerticalSpacer()
                    
                    if exerciseShetViewModel.state.activityType == .other {
                        let customNameBinding = Binding<String>(
                            get: { exerciseShetViewModel.state.customActivityName ?? "" },
                            set: { exerciseShetViewModel.updateCustomName($0) }
                        )
                        CustomTextfield(textInput: customNameBinding, title: "Activity Name")
                    }
                }
                
                Group {
                    let durationBinding = Binding<ModelDuration?>(
                        get: { exerciseShetViewModel.state.duration },
                        set: { exerciseShetViewModel.updateDuration($0) }
                    )
                    CustomDurationPicker(duration: durationBinding)
                    
                    oneVerticalSpacer()
                    
                    let distanceBinding = Binding<ModelDistance?>(
                        get: { exerciseShetViewModel.state.distance },
                        set: { exerciseShetViewModel.updateDistance($0) }
                    )
                    CustomDistanceField(distance: distanceBinding)
                }
                
                Group {
                    
                    let dateBinding = Binding<Date?>(
                        get: { exerciseShetViewModel.state.activityDate },
                        set: { exerciseShetViewModel.updateActivityDate($0) }
                    )
                    
                    CustomDatePicker(title: "Date", date: dateBinding, components: .date)
                    
                    oneVerticalSpacer()
                    
                    CustomDatePicker(
                        title: "Time of Day",
                        date: dateBinding,
                        style: .compact,
                        components: .hourAndMinute
                    )
                    
                    oneVerticalSpacer()
                }
                
                Group {
                    let caloriesBinding = Binding<String>(
                        get: { String(exerciseShetViewModel.state.calories ?? 0) },
                        set: { exerciseShetViewModel.updateCalories(Int($0))}
                    )
                    CustomTextfield(
                        textInput: caloriesBinding,
                        title: "Calories (Optional)",
                        keyboardType: .numberPad
                    )
                    
                    oneVerticalSpacer()
                    
                    let exertionBinding = Binding(
                        get: { exerciseShetViewModel.state.exertion },
                        set: { exerciseShetViewModel.updateExertion($0)}
                    )
                    CustomDropdown(
                        optionSelected: exertionBinding,
                        title: "Preceived Exertion (Optional)",
                        options: ModelPreceivedExertion.allCases
                    )
                }
                
                Spacer() // <---- THIS IS THE SPACER I'M TALKING ABOUT
                    .frame(minHeight: -1)
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    CustomButton(
                        buttonTitle: "Ok",
                        buttonFrame: .small,
                        buttonAction: {}
                    )
                }
            }
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Glass Card View

```
struct GlassCard<Content: View>: View {
    let content: () -> Content
    let backgroundImageName: String?
    
    init(backgroundImageName: String? = nil, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
        self.backgroundImageName = backgroundImageName
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if backgroundImageName != nil {
                Image(backgroundImageName!, bundle: .main)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .blur(radius: 4.0)
            }
            
            ColorTheme.primaryCardColor
            
            content()
                .padding(SpacingTheme.one)
        }
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: SpacingTheme.one))
    }
}
```

When I set the spacer flagged above to have `.fixedSize()` modifier, it looks like this

[image: iPhoneProMax with Fixed Size]
[image: iPhoneSE with fixed size]

When I don't have the fixed size I get the following

[image: iPhoneProMax without Fixed size]
[image: iphoneSE without fixed size]

I tried setting the `minSize` to 2 (and 0) and it still did a huge space on the smaller device.

I've also tried setting view priority and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the Image is stretching your ZStack beyond the bounds of the sheet (GlassCard). With a fixed size for the Spacer everything is centered within your VStack, but otherwise the Spacer takes up all available space (ZStack is scaled to fit the image) and pushes the views to the edges of the ZStack and beyond the bounds of your sheet.

The easiest way to prevent this is to set the image as a background of the ZStack instead of a child:

```
ZStack {
    ColorTheme.primaryCardColor
    
    content()
        .padding(SpacingTheme.one)
}   .background {
        if backgroundImageName != nil {
            Image(backgroundImageName!, bundle: .main)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .blur(radius: 4.0)
        }
    }
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: SpacingTheme.one))
```